# send browser URL via Zapier Push button

Tags: push, zapier

I'm using Zapier push button chrome extension and I need some way to automatically collect the browser URL so I can push it to a webhook so we can use it in WooCommerce store to build an affiliate product. 
But I can't find a way how to collect the browser URL.

Anybody who can point me how to get this done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

David from Zapier here.

As of right now that's not currently possible but it's on our short-term roadmap. Hopefully we'll get that released soon.

For future reference, the best place to get answers is by contacting support, available at contact@zapier.com.

Thanks for your interest in Push!

Comment: Any update so far for this Push feature? Because I don't see anything yet while you say it was on "short-term" roadmap.

Comment: Hey there @Connect2! Sorry, forgot to update here - we pushed this update in late March. If you retest your zap, you should be able to retest your trigger and see the url from the triggered page. Let me know if that's not showing up.